# In Python/Kivy audio_ffpyplayer is not playin instead of audio_sdl2

Tags: python, kivy

I want my project to play audio with only `ffpyplayer` instead of `audio_sdl2`. I added some stuff with a help of someone on this website and it worked on pc. But when I converted it to `apk` with `buildozer`, on my phone it doesn't plays audio. The app works smoothly but without audio. Here's my `python` code:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"
import ffpyplayer
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

class MainWidget(MDFloatLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.path = "sounds/click_effect.wav"
        self.song = SoundLoader.load(self.path)

    def play_on(self):
        self.ids.my_image.source = 'icons/play_pressed.png'
        click = SoundLoader.load('sounds/click_effect.wav')
        if click:
            click.play()

    def play_off(self):
        self.ids.my_image.source = 'icons/play.png'
        myapp.screen_manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left', duration=.25)
        myapp.screen_manager.current = 'Second'
```

And here's my `kivy` code:

```
<MainWidget>:

    Button:
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        pos_hint: {'x': .39, 'y': .1}
        size_hint: .28, .15
        on_press: root.play_on()
        on_release: root.play_off()

        Image:
            id: my_image
            source: "icons/play.png"
            size: 350, 350
            allow_stretch: True
            allow_ratio: True
            keep_ratio: True
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

Aand here's my `buildozer.spec` requirmentes:

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav,ttf,txt

#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png
source.include_patterns = icons/*.png,sounds/*.wav

# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,ffpyplayer
```

[image]

Also I debugged the app and I found this when I click the button:

```
[WARNING] [Audio ] Unable to find a loader for </data/data/org.test.test/files/app/sounds/click_effect.wav>
```

Comment: On Android doen not recommend using `ffpyplayer`, use [MediaPlayer](https://gist.github.com/tito/8da5ee1d51cd81c556da947b225bcc2b)

Comment: Is it better than `audio_sdl2`?

Comment: Yes, it is an android player

Comment: Okay but when I tried to install module in pycharm error is born: `'Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at C:\...'`
It won't install jnius

Comment: Yes, it is only for android (java). Add `jnius` to your `.spec` file

Comment: What do you mean by that? Basically how do I get pass this error? Can you tell me how to install `jnius` in pycharm?

Comment: I can't even install jnius module in pycharm to continue coding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235478/discussion-between-gurami-supatashvili-and-neizvestnyj).